# How to avoid old xib cache on released iphone apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, caching, xib

I'm developing my first iPhone app.

One day, I renamed some files including xib file and its view controller.
After that, my app began to use old xib file.

I deleted xib file, but the old xib still was used.
The code to init view controller was:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
```

I modified the code to:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Then my app used the new xib instead of the old xib.

The question is, is it possible that old xib files are displayed not only on developing apps but also on released apps for some reasons?

Can I avoid old nix caching on released apps if I use `initWithNibName:` instead of `init`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to remove the files in DerivedData.  I've been through this sort of thing.  If you're using the Simulator, I'd also reset the simulator or delete its files.

Paths:

/Users/yourname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

/Users/yourname/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator

You could get fussy, but I usually delete the DerivedData directory when I am having trouble.  Xcode will rebuild them in less time that it takes to worry about the problem.  In the iPhoneSimulator, you can find your app fairly easily and delete that directory if you choose.

Answer (score 0):

In Product->Clean and then after Execute this will be solve your problem.

Comment: thanks. But Product->Clean solves only for developing apps. The users of apps can't do Product->Clean on their iPhones.

Comment: hey user can't create xib in application ones application created it will be working on iphone user haven't able to access xib or other code.

Comment: xib cache problem can't happen on iPhone of users of apps?

Comment: [yourview removeFromSuperview]; try this.